# Is my (Chrome) email address available to websites when I'm logged into Chrome?

Tags: chrome, identity, identity-management

When I'm logged into Chrome (e.g. with my Gmail account) can websites view/obtain the email address associated with my Google/Chrome account? For example, as a means to "recognize" me?

Comment: Yes, but only if you log into another site using your google account... (Oauth2) 
 https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/10130420?sjid=9100111839519668255-NA#siwg

Answer (score 2):

**No.** Chrome doesn't disclose the email address associated with your Gmail account to websites without your consent. This would constitute an information leak vulnerability you could report to [Google's VRP](https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/chrome-rewards/).

That said, they may be able to determine *if* you're logged, e.g. via timing attacks.

Even extensions need the [`chrome.identity`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) API permissions to access your email address and other information about your account.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, as far as I know, they **do not have access** to your email address by default. The website needs to request [permission](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people) to see it. This permission is given for example to use single-sign on.

That being said, I would not rely on it too much. It is OK for not revealing your email to websites that could spam your inbox but not really comforting enough to use when anonymity is required. Then again, you should not use Chrome when you need privacy.

PS: That being said, the current UI is terrible at explaining you are giving away your email address. It used to be you had to explicitly allow basic profile information. Now it seems you just need to use the single sign-on and the basic info is provided by default.